# Can you please tell me the Advantages and Disadvantages of IExceptionhandler?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Can Any one tell me the Advantages and Disadvantages of IExceptionhandler used in web api?
Which one is the best method to handle Exceptions in web Api?

In My below sample i am using IExceptionHandler to handle all my web api exceptions.
In HandleCore method, i am handling Httpexceptions,MyCustomerrormessages,Unhandled Exceptions.
Can any one tell me,handling all the exceptions inside my HandleCore method of IExceptionHandler is a correct way?

namespace AccessServices.EntityModel
{

```
/// <summary>
/// To Handle the unhandled exceptions caught by Web API. 
/// </summary>
public class CustomExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public virtual Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context,
                                    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!ShouldHandle(context))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        return HandleAsyncCore(context, cancellationToken);
    }

    public virtual Task HandleAsyncCore(ExceptionHandlerContext context,
                                        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HandleCore(context);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public virtual void HandleCore(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
    }

    public virtual bool ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        return context.ExceptionContext.CatchBlock.IsTopLevel;
    }

}

/// <summary>
///Response to unhandled exceptions caught by Web API.
/// </summary>
public class OopsExceptionHandler : CustomExceptionHandler
{
    public override void HandleCore(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        var exception = context.Exception;

        if (exception is HttpException)
          {
             var httpException = (HttpException)exception;
              context.Result = new TextPlainErrorResult
              {
                  Request = context.ExceptionContext.Request,
                  Content = exception.Message,
                  Statuscode=(HttpStatusCode)httpException.GetHttpCode()
              };

          }
        else if (exception is MyCustomException)
        {

         context.Result = new TextPlainErrorResult
            {
                //Request = context.ExceptionContext.Request,
                Content = MyCustomException.Message,
                Statuscode = MyCustomException.StatusCode
            };

        }

          else
          {
            context.Result = new TextPlainErrorResult
                                   {
                                       Request = context.ExceptionContext.Request,
                                       Content = "Oops! Sorry! Something went wrong." +
                                                 "Please contact Administrator",
                                        Statuscode=HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
                                   };
          }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends HttpResponseMessage to the client
    /// </summary>
    private class TextPlainErrorResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public HttpStatusCode Statuscode { get; set; }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(Statuscode)

                               {
                                  Content = new StringContent(Content),
                                  RequestMessage = Request
                               };
           return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

`IExceptionHandler` intention is to provide a global error handling mechanism for unhandled exceptions occurring in Web API.

ExceptionFilterAttributes can handle exceptions only from certain areas of Web API…for example, in case of any exceptions thrown from Authentication filters, Authorization filters, Action filters & Actions.

If exceptions are thrown, for example, from MessageHandlers, route matching or when writing out response, then exception filters are not invoked as they sit high up in the layered stack. So Global Error Handling feature (`IExceptionLogger` and `IExceptionHandler`) here try to provide a consistent experience throughout all the layers.

Comment: 1.IF IExceptionHandler have any Disadvantages?     2.Shall i use IExceptionhandler alone or both to my Web Api?

Comment: @user3331492: I am not clear on your second question. can you elaborate more?

Comment: Sahll i use IExceptionhandler alone to handle all my Web api Exceptions or else i have to implement both exception filter and Exception handler?

Comment: Using ExceptionHandler alone should be enough.

Comment: Handling all the exceptions inside my HandleCore method of IExceptionHandler is a correct way(Like i had mentioned in my sample)?